# postgresql can't reindex template1.pg_class_oid_index

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm having an issue where the database `template1` has a corrupted index `pg_class_oid_index`, and the `psql` command complains and asks for it to be reindexed. Yet, I cannot connect to it because it needs to be reindexed! What's the way around this?

```
$ psql -X template1
psql: FATAL:  index "pg_class_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 3
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
$ reindexdb --all
reindexdb: reindexing database "gitlabhq_production"
reindexdb: reindexing database "postgres"
reindexdb: reindexing database "template1"
reindexdb: could not connect to database dbname=template1: FATAL:  index "pg_class_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 3
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
$ psql -X postgres
psql (9.6.11)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# reindex index template1.pg_class_oid_index;
ERROR:  schema "template1" does not exist
postgres=# \c template1;
FATAL:  index "pg_class_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 3
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
Previous connection kept
postgres=#
$ export PGOPTIONS="-P"
$ psql template1
psql: FATAL:  index "pg_class_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 3
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
$ postgres --single -D data/ template1
FATAL:  index "pg_class_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 3
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
$ postgres --single -P -D data/
FATAL:  database "gitlab-psql" does not exist
$ postgres --single -P -D data template1

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.6.11
backend> reindex index pg_class_oid_index;
ERROR:  index "pg_class_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 3
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
STATEMENT:  reindex index pg_class_oid_index;

backend>
```

I can't use the `reindexdb` command and can't connect to it directly, single-user mode didn't help, and the `PGOPTIONS` environment variable didn't help as suggested at https://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/07bhn4xnnc/hint-please-reindex-it didn't help. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reindexing the whole table seems to have fixed my issue.

```
$ postgres --single -P -D data template1

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.6.11
backend> reindex system template1;
CTRL-D
$ postgres --single -P -D data template1

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.6.11
backend> $
```

And I was able to continue with the Gitlab upgrade.